# In Firebase Android, retrieve the value of a child node and save it in a boolean variable

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[I want to retrieve the value of admin and check if its true or false.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1rji.png)

My code:

```
final Boolean[] ifadmin = new Boolean[1];
DatabaseReference admin=mFirebaseuser.child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("admin");
admin.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        System.out.print("ifadmin"+ ifadmin[0]);
        ifadmin[0] = (boolean) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        System.out.print("ifadmin"+ ifadmin[0]);
        // do your stuff here with value

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});

if(ifadmin[0]){
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, AdminActivity.class);
    System.out.println("uid1 "+auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Ideally I should get true or false for `if(ifadmin[0])` but I get a null pointer exception.

I am new to Android and Firebase, Please help me with this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of the boolean admin filed, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        boolean admin = dataSnapshot.child("admin").getValue(Boolean.class);
        Log.d("TAG", admin);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The output should be: `true`

Comment: It's still showing the null pointer exception @alex , the program is not going in the onDataChange function so Log.d("TAG",admin) is not shown.

Comment: This means that `auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()` is `null`. Are you sure you are getting the correct uid?

Comment: Yes It gives https://projectx-971e6.firebaseio.com/users/lMED8FHX7lQNkItwoYbiPNS7Mgq2 which is correct @Alex

Comment: I cannot access that link. Try to use `DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Users").child("lMED8FHX7lQNkItwoYbiPNS7Mgq2");` Does it work?

Comment: uidRef's value is not null, its giving the right value. But the program is not going in onDataChange.

Comment: I understand. Just tell me if you use this line of code: `DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Users").child("lMED8FHX7lQNkItwoYbiPNS7Mgq2")‌​;` if it works.

Comment: after using `DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Users").child("lMED8FHX7lQNkItwoYbiPNS7Mgq2")‌`​‌​ I get a non null value for uidRef (which was happening for `DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid())` as well but the program still doesn't go in `onDataChange()`.

Comment: If you get a `non null` value means that `onDataChange()` was triggered otherwise you couldn't get the value. So the problem in your code is, that `auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()` does not return `"lMED8FHX7lQNkItwoYbiPNS7Mgq2"` it returns `null`. To need to veirfy to get the correct value. Ok?

Comment: it might seem weird, but `auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()` does return `lMED8FHX7lQNkItwoYbiPNS7Mgq2` but still onDataChange() is not triggered :(

Comment: You said that you got a `non null` value for the admin. Which was that?

Comment: since onDataChange() is not triggered, I am not getting a value for admin. I am getting non null for uidRef (reference to admin)

Comment: So if is a `non null` value for `uidRef ` means it returns something. What does it return?

Comment: It returns `https://projectx-971e6.firebaseio.com/users/lMED8FHX7lQNkItwoYbiPNS7Mgq2`

Comment: It's perfect. Now try to use this: `Log.d("TAG", dataSnapshot);` What does it print?

Comment: Since onDataChange() is not triggered, I am unable to print `Log.d("TAG", dataSnapshot)` in onDataChange.

Comment: If you are saying that `uidRef ` return the correct path and the `onDataChange()` is not triggered means that you are using other code that i provided you. That code works 100%. Is tested.  Show me a screen-shot of your class file.

Comment: `DatabaseReference rootRef =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();  DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("users").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()); System.out.println("uid1 "+uidRef); ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {@Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { Log.d("TAG", ""+dataSnapshot);
   ifadmin[0] = dataSnapshot.child("admin").getValue(Boolean.class); Log.d("hey", ""+ifadmin[0]); }@Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {   } };
 uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);`

Comment: Don't use ifadmin[0], use the boolean directly as indicated above . Don't use any array.

Comment: Yeah! It finally worked! I don't know why admin[0] caused a problem.